# Downgrade minikube version on windows

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have minikube installed on windows using below command

```
choco install minikube
```

But it installed minikube version v1.12.1, Now i want to downgrade minikube to v1.8.2 . How this can be achieved. Alternatively, How can i install a specific version of minikube?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=choco+install+specific+version

Comment: That seems the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/31256031/34092 - just changing the `virtualbox ` to `minikube` and the `4.3.26` to `1.8.2`?

Comment: Great, Its working. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can downgrad it simply but you can delete/uninstall it and then can install with version which you need.

With Commands

```
$ minikube stop
$ minikube delete
```

I am refering a post as well which can help you
[How to completely uninstall Minikube in windows 10 Pro? (chocolatey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53263586/how-to-completely-uninstall-minikube-in-windows-10-pro-chocolatey/53271159)

Comment: I am not getting any command to install a specific version of minikube.

Comment: use this command `choco install minikube --version 1.29.0 --force --allow-downgrade`